# MobileConnnect - customized "From" name & behaviour?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

The MobileConnect instance that I work with, is based on a shared shortcode and then when we send texts out, we use a custom from name - and that is fine.

Whenever we send an sms, it comes through fine with the correct from name. On iPhone, when i click the name - everything is blank, and i cannot do anything. However, if I click on the "i" that takes me to the details page, the call icon - all of a sudden - i highlighted, and when I press it, it starts dialing a (to us) unknown number.

Shared shortcode: 1235
Number it calls: 25 62 72 63

Does anyone know how to disable this? (or at least, how to modify the number that it tries to call?)

Along the same lines:
I know we can customize the from name, but can we make it so that it appears that the sms comes from a particular number (e.g. the customer's account manager) and then make reply texts / clicks / calls on the custom sender, go directly to the account manager?

Finally, can we create a custom name e.g. from company, but then customize the number that can be called through it?